# How to check if content exist before submission

Tags: php

I have this code.

```
<?php

$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
$message1  .= "D: ".$_POST['mydate']."\n";
$message2  .= "FN: ".$_POST['fname']."\n";
$message3  .= "LN: ".$_POST['lname']."\n";
$message4  .= "Em: ".$_POST['email']."\n";
$message5  .= "AltEm: ".$_POST['altemail']."\n";
$message6  .= "Tel: ".$_POST['tel']."\n";
$message7  .= "Natnlty: ".$_POST['addre']."\n";
$message8  .= "Age: ".$_POST['age']."\n";
$message9  .= "Occ: ".$_POST['occupy']."\n";
$message10  .= "ID: ".$_POST['wini']."\n";
$message11  .= "Lang: ".$_POST['lang']."\n";
$message12 .= "IP: ".$ip."\n";
$message13  .= "-----------------------\n";

 $content = file('store/em.php');
 if(in_array($message4, $content)) \\what do i do here

 $content = file('store/c.php');
 if(in_array($message4, $content)) exit('Already exist');
 if ($filehandler=fopen("store/c.php","a"))
   {
fwrite($filehandler,$message1.$message2.$message3.$message4.$message5.$message6.$message7.$message8.$message9.$message10.$message11.$message12.$message13);

fclose($filehandler);

       header("Location: thanks.php");
   }
```

?>

I want to check if $message4 exist in store/em.php if it exist, execution should continue. if it does not exist, exit and echo something.

With this side of the code below i'm able to check duplicate content for $message4

```
$content = file('store/c.php');
if(in_array($message4, $content)) exit('Already exist');
```

My question is, how do i check if $message4 exist in em.php before checking for duplicate content on c.php

Comment: You asked this already http://stackoverflow.com/q/28308632/ - what is it now? This looks like an exact duplicate to me.

Comment: FYI: You don't have a question in this/your 'question'/'post'!

Comment: This is a different one. Please read carefully

Comment: I did. Not much difference besides a folder and filename being different and an added function.

Comment: what does em.php contain?

Comment: `strlen($content > 0) || !empty($content)` ?

Comment: @mxlfa em.php contains emails.

Comment: please see at the point where i wrote \\what do i do here

Comment: @bobos How should we know what you write and do?!

Comment: There have been several methods posted here and your other question, which you clearly stated you could made work.
How are what you're doing now any different? Please try being more clear.

Comment: *"My question is, how do i check if $message4 exist in em.php before checking for duplicate content on c.php"* - Um... `$content = file('store/em.php');
if(in_array($message4, $content)) exit('Already exist');` *perhaps?*

Comment: @Fred-ii-, yes but it shouldn't exit. it should continue for em.php but exit for c.php

Comment: It's just a question of messing around with your conditional statement. Using either the `&&` or `||` operator, depending on what you want; both or one of.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i can see you understand me correctly...but what should i do if it does not exist in em.php? Note: if it exist in em.php, it is okay. but if it does not exist there...it is not okay...the execution should die.

Comment: `if(condition meets) { do something } else{ do something else }` basically.

Comment: @Fred-ii- that's my problem, i cant write it.

Comment: Please, if you can write it for me, this is exactly what i want. if $message4 exist in em.php, continue to check for duplicate content on c.php if it does not exist in em.php exit and exit and echo something.

Comment: Not sure about this, `$content = file('store/em.php'); 
if(in_array($message4, $content)){
fwrite(...);
}
else{
$content = file('store/c.php');
fwrite(...);
}

fclose($filehandler);`

Comment: if condition meets, it should continue not write

Comment: You get the basic method of what I meant. `if/else`. I have to go now, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
$content = file_get_contents('store/em.php');
if(strpos($content, $message4) !== false) {
 exit('Already exist');
} else {
// ...
}
```